# Is it meaningful to test very simple Angular controllers?

Tags: angularjs, testing

This is one of our controllers. It is a very simple controller as you can see.

```
angular.
module("printing").
controller("PrintController", function PrintController(
    $window,
    localize,
    PartsEnum,
    IsBitIncluded
) {
    "use strict";

    this.PartsEnum = ExamPartsEnum;
    this.IsBitIncluded = IsBitIncluded;

    this.origin = $window.location.protocol + "//" + $window.location.host;

    this.optionsText = [
        localize.get("Yes"),
        localize.get("Maybe"),
        localize.get("No"),
    ];
});
```

- Should we write tests for this controller? If you need more information to be able to answer this, write information would sway your answer in any direction
- What should we test about this controller? It does almost nothing. What is there to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in all honesty I would not write a test to test the logic in this controller perse since as you stated it does very little. What I would test is to check that **your origin url is correctly formated** and that the **"yes", "maybe", "or" options exist on your scope**. That way when someone in the future modifies something he will know that he broke something when the tests are run

so basically it boils down to:

1. testing functionality that you have written
2. testing modifications in the future and providing a safety net

Comment: For completeness/code coverage, I would also assert the other two properties are set.